# Arranging collapsed data in a table

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a collapsed data as shown below, where I have ID & its header below the header its value exists. Each ID has its own different no of headers & values.

[image]

I have to arrange them into a table where i have consolidated headers of all the IDs into one row and the IDs are in one column. Based one the ID i need to update the respective header's value below.

```
ID--+--H1--+--H2--+--H3--+--H4--+--H5--|
18219--V1--+--V3--+--  --+--  --+--  --|    
18218--V2--+--V4--+--  --+--  --+--  --|
18217--V1--+--V2--+--V3--+--V4--+--V5--|
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

    Dim arrContent As Variant
    Dim strSource As String
    Dim strDest As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim objHeader As Object
    Dim objItem As Variant
    Dim lngColsCount As Long

    ' set initial values
    strSource = "source" ' source worksheet name
    strDest = "destination" ' destination worksheet name
    y = 1 ' source worksheet first ID cell's row number
    x = 2 ' source worksheet first ID cell's column number
    Set objHeader = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' pack source data into array of dictionaries
    objHeader.Add "ID", 0
    arrContent = Array()
    With Sheets(strSource)
        Do While .Cells(y, x).Value <> "" And .Cells(y + 1, x).Value = ""
            Set objItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            objItem.Add 0, .Cells(y, x).Value
            p = x + 1
            Do While .Cells(y, p).Value <> ""
                If Not objHeader.Exists(.Cells(y, p).Value) Then objHeader.Add .Cells(y, p).Value, objHeader.Count
                objItem(objHeader(.Cells(y, p).Value)) = .Cells(y + 1, p).Value
                p = p + 1
            Loop
            ReDim Preserve arrContent(UBound(arrContent) + 1)
            Set arrContent(UBound(arrContent)) = objItem
            y = y + 2
        Loop
    End With

    ' output
    With Sheets(strDest)
        .Cells.Delete
        lngColsCount = UBound(objHeader.keys)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lngColsCount + 1)).Value = objHeader.keys
        y = 2
        For Each objItem In arrContent
            For x = 1 To lngColsCount + 1
                .Cells(y, x).Value = objItem(x - 1)
            Next
            y = y + 1
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

For source table:

[image: source]

it generates output:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi @omegastripes, thanks a lot for your help. Im getting error on ".Cells.Delete" and "With Sheets(strSource)".

Hope we need convert the values to string, could you please take a look at it.

Comment: Plz ignore the previous comment. Now the macro is running but all my headers & ID's were gone in the destination sheet. (I didn't modified anything in the above code). And i have  9300 rows in the source sheet each ID have different no. of heading.

Comment: Take a look at screenshots of the source and destination worksheets in my answer (open full-sized for detailed view). Are they looking like you need?

Comment: Ya but in my file its giving me a blank destination sheet only. Anything i missed?

Comment: Im using excel 2007 is it problem ?

Comment: Excel 2007 should work. Make sure that you have assigned the right values to `x` and `y` vars, they should point to the column and row of the cell, containing first ID (in my example this cell is selected, with `18219`, so `x = 2`, `y = 1`).

Comment: Oooh Yeah now its working :)
Thanks a lot, if you have time could you please explain how its working.

Comment: Sure thing. But first you have to learn [`Scripting.Dictionary` ActiveX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx) methods and properties, also [`Sheets`, `Worksheet` objects, `Worksheet.Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068.aspx) to know the syntax like `Sheets(Name).Cells(y, x).Value`, and [`With ... End With` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: In my previous comment there are three links, click them and read that articles carefully. Then ask questions if yiu have.